# Convert date string to datetime format python

Tags: python

I have dates like ‘feb-97’, ‘jan-02’, ‘dec-22’ in a dataframe and want to convert the column to datetime format with day as start or last day of month.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['feb-97', 'jan-02', 'dec-22']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b-%y')
```

```
date
0   1997-02-01
1   2002-01-01
2   2022-12-01
```